# Перестал запускаться Apache 24

Tags: php, apache

У меня в файле httpd.conf прописано следующее:

```
Define SRVROOT "D:/work/httpd/Apache24"
PHPIniDir "D:/work/php-7"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php7_module D:/work/php-7/php7apache2_4.dll
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

В файле httpd-vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site1.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/site1.com"
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    ErrorLog "logs/site1.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/site1.com-access.log" common
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/docs/site1.com">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при открытии страницы site1.com появлялась версия php, но когда строка `LoadModule php7_module D:/work/php-7/php7apache2_4.dll` не закоментирована, то Apache просто не запускается. То есть, я пишу команду `httpd -k start` и вообще ничего не происходит, в итоге сервер не запущен. Если строку закоментировать, то сервер запускается. С синтаксисом все в норме. PHP установлен, все пути совпадают. Версия Apache httpd-2.4.41-win64-VS16, PHP php-7.4.3-Win32-vc15-x64

Comment: За всю историю косяков ни разу не встречался с ситуацией, чтобы ни в логах, ни в командной строке не вывелось сообщение об ошибке. Но на всякий случай проверьте php. Запустите в консоли хотя бы `php -v`

Comment: Может всё-таки, нужно сначала загрузить DLL, а уже после этого добавлять handler? А то у вас это наоборот (сначала обработчик пытаетесь загрузить, а потом DLL для него)

Comment: ArchDemon, огромное спасибо за совет. Выяснилось, что у меня не было прописано пути до php в переменной PATH и не установлен microsoft Visual C ++ Redistributable. Теперь все работает.